# Android radio stream metadata notification

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stream, streaming, android-mediaplayer

i was looking for Android libraries which are able to fetch metadata stuff e.g. artist, title from radio streams. I've found these 2 libs which are capable of that:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/streamscraper/ 
https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

And there's also ffmpeg available, where the libraries have first to be compiled for Android.

The above libs haven't a listener interface for getting informed about song changes. The only possible solution is to poll every couple of seconds, and check old artist and title with the new ones. But I think this will drain the smartphone batteries quite a lot.

Is there a way to get notified if radio song changes? Maybe with ffmpeg?